# How to render this js with mustache and dropdown

Tags: javascript, php

I have this element and i would know how to rendre the elements with mustache inside dropdown ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function Mycategory_id() {
    $("#myAjax").on('click', function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.my_ajax_file.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
          //data returned from php
          var options_html = '';
          for(index in data){
            var category_id = data[index]['categories_id'];
            var category_name = data[index]['categories_name'];
            options_html += '<option value="'+category_id+'">' + category_name + '</option>';

          }
          $('#category_id').html(options_html);
        }
      });
    )};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create dropdown option attribute in http://www.my_ajax_file.php file and return it.

For example:

```
$result = array();
echo "<option value='".$option_value."'>".$option_name."</option>";
```